# Prevent raising SizeChanged event in base class from derived class

Tags: c#, silverlight

I am trying to derive from Silverlight.Controls.ToolTips.ToolTipService, and want to change the functionality of the SizeChanged event. 
The OnToolTipSizeChanged is not a virtual method, so I cannot override it. I need something like e.Handled = true that exists in MouseButtonEventArgs.

The reason I want all this is that Silverlight.Controls.ToolTips.ToolTipService.OnToolTipSizeChanged method throws me a NullReferenceException with no obvious reason.

Do you have any idea? please help, cause I have no success in finding something on this issue or close to it... thanks in advance!

Comment: We are talking about the `ToolTipService` class of the framework or some other class?

Comment: We are talking about ToolTipService class of the Silverlight.Controls.ToolTips namespace

Comment: Silverlight [ToolTipService](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.tooltipservice(v=vs.95).aspx) is a static class. It is no FrameworkElement and does not have a SizeChanged event.

Comment: This is the stack track of the exception I got:
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Silverlight.Controls.ToolTips.ToolTipService.OnToolTipSizeChanged(Object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.SizeChangedEventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnSizeChanged(Object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
   at MS.Internal.JoltHelper.RaiseEvent(IntPtr target, UInt32 eventId, IntPtr coreEventArgs, UInt32 eventArgsTypeInde